# How to change streaming resolution on the fly in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am developing a video streaming application in Android. I am calling an API to get the streaming url from server, which i am giving to the mediaplayer to play. I have a requirement to show in the UI, an option to change the video resolution on the fly. How can i achieve this changing of video quality/resolution (eg. 144p to 720p) on the fly without interrupting the flow of the playing video.I have explore ExoPlayer and below is my code for track selection.I am little confuse how can i force the track selector to play to a specified bitrate/resolution from here on

```
 BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
```

Comment: what min api level is supported?

Comment: I am supporting my app from min sdk 16

Comment: if it were 23 you could use `setDataSource (MediaDataSource dataSource)` and implement your own custom `MediaDataSource`, with 16 the only option is [exoplayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer) imho

Comment: okk, can switch to exoplayer. Not an issue at all.Can you explain me how can i achieve it using exoplayer

Comment: Any code snippet will be helpful or documentation link

Comment: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#customization - you need to read about custom `DataSource`s

Comment: Say i have the option to choose between multiple resolution videos (144p,240p,720p) etc. Firstly i want to know does my server needs to have these 3 different resolution videos at their end?? Or one video of the highest resolution is enough

Comment: Secondly, do i need to call my API each time i choose my video resolution on the fly to get that specific resolution streaming url, or once i call for the first time and i get the resolution of big video, since then i can change the video quality using exoplayer without making any further api call?

Comment: `"Or one video of the highest resolution is enough"`? it all depends how you implement your server side - you can scale down your hi resolution video on the fly or you can use some cache of already used resolutions or ...

Comment: Can it be achieved using Exoplayer if the file format of the video is a normal mp4 file

Comment: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html

Comment: I have explored Exoplayer and below is my code

Comment: How can i user track selecter here to set my m2u8 to play to a specific resolution